# Рассчитать вероятности разных исходов (комбинаторика)

Tags: комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей

Меня интересует такая вот задачка по комбинаторике/теорверу.

Дано:
Есть 16 ячеек. 3 типа символа - нет символа (NO), символ1 (SYM1), символ2 (SYM2).
Кол-во символов:
NO - 9 шт.
SYM1 - 4 шт.
SYM2 - 3 шт.
В каждой ячейки случайно оказывается один из символов. Человек не знает в какой ячейки какой символ. Человек случайным образом выбирает 3 ячейки.

Вопрос:
Какая вероятность угадать, к примеру, 2 шт. символа1 и 1 шт. символ2 ?

Что я уже сделал:

Я знаю как решать эту задачу если бы типов символа было два - нет символа (12штук) и символ1 (4шт).

Вероятности угадать символ1 для такого случая вычисляются по формуле:

```
W (Guessed) = Combin(4; Guessed) * Combin(16-4; 3-Guessed) / Combin(16; 3) * 100
```

где Guessed - количество угаданных символ1 (0, 1, 2, или 3 шт.)

Понимаю, что всего есть 10 разных исходов в случае с тремя типами символов (в скобках сколько символов угадано):

```
Исход 1: NO(3), SYM1(0), SYM2(0)
Исход 2: NO(2), SYM1(1), SYM2(0)
Исход 3: NO(2), SYM1(0), SYM2(1)
Исход 4: NO(1), SYM1(0), SYM2(2)
Исход 5: NO(1), SYM1(1), SYM2(1)
Исход 6: NO(1), SYM1(2), SYM2(0)
Исход 7: NO(0), SYM1(0), SYM2(3)
Исход 8: NO(0), SYM1(1), SYM2(2)
Исход 9: NO(0), SYM1(2), SYM2(1)
Исход 10: NO(0), SYM1(3), SYM2(0)
```

Но как мне рассчитать вероятности каждого из исходов?

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К успешному результату ведут такие комбинации

```
SYM1 SYM1 SYM2
SYM1 SYM2 SYM1
SYM2 SYM1 SYM1
```

Для первой комбинации вероятность того, что

- первым символом будет `SYM1` равна `4/16`,
- первым и вторым символами будут `SYM1` – `4/16 * 3/15`
- первым и вторым будут `SYM1`, а третьим – `SYM2` равна `4/16 * 3/15 * 3/14`

Вероятность выпадения второй и третьей комбинации считаются аналогично:
`4/16 * 3/15 * 3/14` и `3/16 * 4/15 * 3/14` соответственно

Итого `4/16 * 3/15 * 3/14 + 4/16 * 3/15 * 3/14 + 3/16 * 4/15 * 3/14 = 9/280`

Для проверки можно посчитать вероятность выпадения одной из оставшихся комбинаций

```
NO   NO   NO    =  9/16 * 8/15 * 7/14
NO   NO   SYM1  =  9/16 * 8/15 * 4/14
NO   NO   SYM2  =  9/16 * 8/15 * 3/14
NO   SYM1 NO    =  9/16 * 4/15 * 8/14
NO   SYM1 SYM1  =  9/16 * 4/15 * 3/14
NO   SYM1 SYM2  =  9/16 * 4/15 * 3/14
NO   SYM2 NO    =  9/16 * 3/15 * 8/14
NO   SYM2 SYM1  =  9/16 * 3/15 * 4/14
NO   SYM2 SYM2  =  9/16 * 3/15 * 2/14
SYM1 NO   NO    =  4/16 * 9/15 * 8/14
SYM1 NO   SYM1  =  4/16 * 9/15 * 3/14
SYM1 NO   SYM2  =  4/16 * 9/15 * 3/14
SYM1 SYM1 NO    =  4/16 * 3/15 * 9/14
SYM1 SYM1 SYM1  =  4/16 * 3/15 * 2/14
SYM1 SYM2 NO    =  4/16 * 3/15 * 9/14
SYM1 SYM2 SYM2  =  4/16 * 3/15 * 2/14
SYM2 NO   NO    =  3/16 * 9/15 * 8/14
SYM2 NO   SYM1  =  3/16 * 9/15 * 4/14
SYM2 NO   SYM2  =  3/16 * 9/15 * 2/14
SYM2 SYM1 NO    =  3/16 * 4/15 * 9/14
SYM2 SYM1 SYM2  =  3/16 * 4/15 * 2/14
SYM2 SYM2 NO    =  3/16 * 2/15 * 9/14
SYM2 SYM2 SYM1  =  3/16 * 2/15 * 4/14
SYM2 SYM2 SYM2  =  3/16 * 2/15 * 1/14
```

Она равна `271/280 = 1 - 9/280`